# Batch Test for JFLAP Turing Machine

Tags: turing-machines, jflap

I built a Turing Machine in JFLAP is a binary adder. It is a 3 tape TM: first two tapes are inputs, and the 3rd tape gets the output. When I try to do the batch testing (info found [here](http://www.cs.duke.edu/csed/jflap/tutorial/batch/batch.htm)), I cannot get the 3rd string in my .txt file to become the output tape. My .txt file is built like:

```
00110 11100110 11001110 accept
10101 010 11101 accept 
111 1111 01101 accept
1010 101 0101 accept
0001 001001010101 001101010101 accept
```

However, because it is a 3 tape machine, and it must be, the last binary string that I want to be the output string is taken as the 3rd input string, which should be blank for all the tests. Is there any way I can format my test strings so JFLAP understands the last string should be the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that I needed to put an extra space after the first two inputs; thus, the 3rd input string would be an empty string. So the first line would be:

```
00110 11100110  11001110 accept
```